Why does el.scrollIntoView() cause the whole container to move?
I have nested overflow-y: auto elements, with a full page which is scrollable, and the sidebar which is independently scrollable. When I hover on something in the main content area, I want the sidebar nav link to scroll into view (to the top or center, if possible), but when I call sideBarNavLink.scrollIntoView(), it scrolls the entire content/page so the whole content goes up and is cut off on the bottom. My page is relatively complicated to reproduce.
Is there some trick to making scrollIntoView reliable and work as you'd expect? Do I need position: relative and stuff like that to get it to work or something? Or do I need to roll my own scroll into view function?


$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.link').click((e) => {
    e.currentTarget.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
  })
})
.page {
  padding: 16px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  padding: 16px;
  background: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
      <li class="link">a</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>



Notice when you click on an "a" (a .link class), it scrolls the whole StackOverflow post into view! Why...

This thread should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751393/scroll-element-into-view-within-container-but-not-in-browser-window

From the documentation: "scrolls the element's ancestor containers such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is called is visible to the user". So since you are calling it with block:"start" as an option, all parent containers are being scrolled until the element is at the start (top) of the view. I don't think there is a way with this method to target a specific parent container.

Even though the linked question suggested in the comments works by changing the scrollTop of the element, it might not be very flexible.
I ended up defining a custom scroll behavior that targets the nearest scrollable container with position and behavior options.
To do so, first, we find the nearest scrollable container. Then calculate the scroll position and scroll to that position using scrollTo:
// Smooth scroll to the target element
function customScrollIntoView(e, {position = 'top', behavior = 'instant'} = {}) {

    // Find the closest scrollable container for the given element
    function findScrollableContainer(element) {
        while (element.length) {
            if (['auto', 'scroll'].includes(element.css('overflow'))) {
                return element;
            }
            element = element.parent();
        }
        return $(window); // Fallback to window if no scrollable container is found
    }

    const container = findScrollableContainer($(e.currentTarget));
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const containerRect = container[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    const targetRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Calculate the new scroll position
    const positions = {
        top: container.scrollTop() + (targetRect.top - containerRect.top),
        center: container.scrollTop() + (targetRect.top - containerRect.top) - (containerRect.height / 2) + (targetRect.height / 2),
        bottom: container.scrollTop() + (targetRect.bottom - containerRect.bottom) + targetRect.height,
    };

    // Smooth scroll to the new position
    container[0].scrollTo({
        top: positions[position],
        behavior: behavior,
    });
}

And this is the result with options set to smooth scrolling to the center of the view:


$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.link').click((e) => {
        customScrollIntoView(e, {behavior: 'smooth'});
    });
});

// Smooth scroll to the target element
function customScrollIntoView(e, {position = 'top', behavior = 'instant'} = {}) {

    // Find the closest scrollable container for the given element
    function findScrollableContainer(element) {
        while (element.length) {
            if (['auto', 'scroll'].includes(element.css('overflow'))) {
                return element;
            }
            element = element.parent();
        }
        return $(window); // Fallback to window if no scrollable container is found
    }

    const container = findScrollableContainer($(e.currentTarget));
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const containerRect = container[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    const targetRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Calculate the new scroll position
    const positions = {
        top: container.scrollTop() + (targetRect.top - containerRect.top),
        center: container.scrollTop() + (targetRect.top - containerRect.top) - (containerRect.height / 2) + (targetRect.height / 2),
        bottom: container.scrollTop() + (targetRect.bottom - containerRect.bottom) + targetRect.height,
    };

    // Smooth scroll to the new position
    container[0].scrollTo({
        top: positions[position],
        behavior: behavior,
    });
}
.page {
  padding: 16px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  padding: 16px;
  background: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li class="link">a1</li>
      <li class="link">a2</li>
      <li class="link">a3</li>
      <li class="link">a4</li>
      <li class="link">a5</li>
      <li class="link">a6</li>
      <li class="link">a7</li>
      <li class="link">a8</li>
      <li class="link">a9</li>
      <li class="link">a10</li>
      <li class="link">a11</li>
      <li class="link">a12</li>
      <li class="link">a13</li>
      <li class="link">a14</li>
      <li class="link">a15</li>
      <li class="link">a16</li>
      <li class="link">a17</li>
      <li class="link">a18</li>
      <li class="link">a19</li>
      <li class="link">a20</li>
      <li class="link">a21</li>
      <li class="link">a22</li>
      <li class="link">a23</li>
      <li class="link">a24</li>
      <li class="link">a25</li>
      <li class="link">a26</li>
      <li class="link">a27</li>
      <li class="link">a28</li>
      <li class="link">a29</li>
      <li class="link">a30</li>
      <li class="link">a31</li>
      <li class="link">a32</li>
      <li class="link">a33</li>
      <li class="link">a34</li>
      <li class="link">a35</li>
      <li class="link">a36</li>
      <li class="link">a37</li>
      <li class="link">a38</li>
      <li class="link">a39</li>
      <li class="link">a40</li>
      <li class="link">a41</li>
      <li class="link">a42</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>



